# How to find undefined variables in a PHP script

Tags: php, unit-testing

Suppose we have following function in PHP:

```
public function testSomething()
{
    $name = perform_sql_query("SELECT name FROM table WHERE id = $entity_id;");
    assert($name == "some_name");
}
```

The query is syntactically correct, but since $entity_id is undefined - the query will always search for 'id = 0', which is semantically incorrect.

I would like such functions to fail automatically, when they try to use an undefined variable. Is there such a mechanism in PHP? Or maybe there is some tool, that can be used to analyze PHP source code to find such cases?

Those undefined variables can occur anywhere in the project, so correct the decision will be to check function arguments in every function.

---

Setting an error handler helped. Now anytime an uninitialized variable is used, an exception is thrown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One issue to consider is that for a live site, you may not want users to see errors and warnings. Some web-hosts provide an *error.log* file which logs PHP errors. Here's a custom error handler for live sites:

```
function log_error($no, $msg, $file, $line)
{
    $errorMessage = "Error no $no: $msg in $file at line number $line";

    file_put_contents("errors_paypal.txt",$errorMessage."\n\n",FILE_APPEND);
}

set_error_handler('log_error');
```

The great thing about this is that you can format it and dump various information you want.

Answer (score 6):

PHP has several severity levels in script errors. You can define what the interpreter should consider an error: Either use the function [`error_reporting()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) or set the [`php.ini`-directive with the same name](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting) for that purpose.

Here is an example for configuring PHP to report *anything* which might lead to errors (this can lead to quite a lot of messages, if you are setting it for the first time, but fixing these errors will give you a much more stable application):

```
# In your PHP script:
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);

# Or in your php.ini file:
error_reporting = E_ALL | E_STRICT
```

Comment: Someone else may want to change error reporting for other reasons and break something.

Comment: If the program is verified to be correct, what's there to break? On production site, setting error reporting to on is a must. You could turn it off for live site, but then see my answer.

Comment: Someone else shouldn't touch the error_reporting level. Or revert it back to its original value, if he *really* must.

Comment: Not always. As the accepted answer sais, sometimes you want error reporting off to fail nicely in production sites.

Comment: No, you don't need to turn error_reporting off, if you have a custom error handler. The error_handler will *always* be called, regardless of current error_reporting level. As the manual states: 'It is important to remember that the standard PHP error handler is completely bypassed.' You should have a look at error handlers in PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php

Comment: It is close to incomprehensible near *"Consider an error"*. Can you fix it?

Comment: @PeterMortensen: Thank you for telling me, and you're right, that was really hard to read. Please let me know if the new version needs further improvement. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

If you turn on [all warning and notices](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php), evaluating that string should throw you an error message.

Also, it will evaluate to invalid SQL (it will be `id=` not `id=0`), so your perform_sql_query should be reporting that also.

Comment: It is not very clear from the link. Do you mean `E_ALL`?

Answer (score 2):

I normally check if my values are null within my function. You can use [isset()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) and also if it's a empty string, using something like below:

```
public function testSomething()
{
    if(!empty($entity_id)){
            $name = perform_sql_query("SELECT name FROM table WHERE id = $entity_id;");
            assert($name == "some_name");
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I would also set the error reporting using the below line:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
```

Comment: use empty() to check for unset or empty variables, it's shorter and more efficient than isset() and !=""

Comment: cheers for that didnt know that. Thought it would raise an error if unset :) Cheers

Answer (score 1):

- Set error reporting to E_ALL in your PHP applications by using:

  error_reporting(E_ALL);

Or by setting appropriate values for the *error_reporting* variable in file *php.ini* or *.htaccess*. This allows you to catch all errors, including those related to undefined variables.

- Set up the PHP *error_log* in your development environment and inspect it carefully during development stages.

Lastly, for the above mentioned code, include all common sense error handling in the "perform_sql_query" function. Your *perform_sql_query* function is probably a wrapper over the *mysql_query* function, so check for errors generated by *mysql_query* (and similar) functions.

Answer (score -2):

Use the [isset()](http://php.net/isset) function before accessing variables.

Comment: it could be set and yet still have a empty value

Comment: -1 The question was not about how to fix the error, it was about how to get PHP to report it.

Comment: getting php to report it is easier, but not safe

Comment: Yes, but the question is: 'How do I *find* the error', not 'How do I *fix* the error'